# Group row values into columns without hardcoding PL SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, syntax

I have a table that looks like this:

| MONTH | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| July | Ally |
| July | Don |
| July | Ken |
| March | Lee |
| March | Froyo |
| March | Denise |
| April | Kram |

I want it to look like this:

| July | March | April |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ally | Lee | Kram |
| Don | Froyo |  |
| Ken | Denise |  |

Here is a solution I have tried:

```
SELECT
(SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE month='July') AS July,
(SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE month='March') AS March,
(SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE month='April') AS April
FROM DUAL;
```

However, I do not want to hardcode the month values like `month='July'`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is, but the request also doesn't really make sense because columns are supposed to be fixed, once you hack them to dynamic you have to hack the ongoing treatment of them to be dynamic too; don't have the database do it, get the front end to do it instead

Comment: " I do not want to hardcode the month values" - why not? There are only **12** months in a year, so ... not that you really need some high-end level query to do that.

Comment: @Littlefoot That is since I dont want the columns with no values to exist

Comment: You could write some code that would dynamically generate the SQL statement that you want.  That adds a fair amount of complexity to the problem and requires you to hit the table twice-- once to get the distinct set of `month` values so that you can build the query and then once to run the actual query.  If your table is large, that could be a significant cost.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to construct a query with conditional aggregate, sorting the month-columns in their order within a year such as

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE
             WHEN month = 'March' THEN
              name
           END) AS March,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN month = 'April' THEN
              name
           END) AS April,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN month = 'July' THEN
              name
           END) AS July
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY month ORDER BY name) AS rn
          FROM t) -- "t" represents your mentioned table
 GROUP BY rn
 ORDER BY rn
```

and you can generate a stored function code as you wish to make it dynamic such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_People_By_Months RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('MAX(CASE WHEN month = '''||month||''' THEN name END) AS '||month ,',') 
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY month_nr)        
    INTO v_cols
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.month, m.month_nr
            FROM t
            JOIN (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level, 'mm'),
                                 'Month',
                                 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS month, 
                         level AS month_nr
                    FROM dual
                  CONNECT BY level <= 12) m
              ON t.month = TRIM(m.month));

  v_sql :='SELECT '|| v_cols ||'
             FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY name) AS rn 
                     FROM t)
            GROUP BY rn 
            ORDER BY rn';


  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

then invoke from the *SQL Developer*'s console as

```sql
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_People_By_Months;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result;
```